# changing font size and text size of listview

Tags: java, android

In my application I have a list view that has an image-button and a text-view.
I want to change font size and font size of my list view by choice of user.
My list view extends from ArrayAdapter. 
 here ARE my code:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
customButtonListener customListner;





public interface customButtonListener {
    public void onButtonClickListner(int position,String value);
}

public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
    this.customListner = listener;
}

private Context context;

private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataItem) {
    super(context, R.layout.child_listview, dataItem);
    this.data = dataItem;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_listview, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childTextView);

       // textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
      //  viewHolder.text = textView;
        viewHolder.Button = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childButton);
        viewHolder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final String temp = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.text.setText(temp);
    viewHolder.Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (customListner != null) {
                customListner.onButtonClickListner(position,temp);
            }

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageButton Button;
}
```

and my main activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    customButtonListener {

private ListView listView;
public TextView textView;

ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> dataItems = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //G.currentActivity = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listdata);
    List<String> dataTemp = Arrays.asList(dataArray);
    dataItems.addAll(dataTemp);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


   // tx.setTypeface(G.defaultFont);
    adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataItems);
    adapter.setCustomButtonListner(MainActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public void onButtonClickListner(int position, String value) {

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = dataItems.get(position);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

how i can do this? any suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean by " by choice of user" ?

Comment: I have 3 fonts , I want user can select a font for whole application . I want user can change the font for whole application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set text size with

```
textView.setTextSize(16) //change value as per your need
```

set font using

```
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font name.ttf");

textView.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Comment: I have different fonts . I want user can change the font. In this way I can just have one font.

Comment: based on user selection change the font name Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font_name.ttf");

Comment: have you putted your font file in assets folder?

Comment: it is in assets folder or assets/fonts/ ?

Comment: they are in the folder named fonts in assets folder.

Comment: I have an error with get asset cause I use this code in my ListAdaptor. cause my textview is in the listadaptor.

Comment: use context.getAssets()

Comment: thanks you very much. Is there any way to chat with u in order to solve mu problem? plz

Comment: You can create a chat window. If my code work then accept it by rating positive

Comment: I'm new with android and this site. I don't konw to use this site very good. by the way thanks. I try to make it.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that if the `textSize` is set in code, calling `textView.setTextSize(X)` interprets the number (X) as `SP`. Use `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, X)` to set values in `dp`.

Comment: TextSize should always be entered as SP, not DP.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a xml layout file defining the layout of your list view item. You can always modify the text size of the textview you might have used in the list view item layout.

For example,

```
android:textSize="somedp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a custom view.

Just create a layout with some textViews and ID's (and if you want, some imageviews) and a class.

IE:

On layout folder:
layout_custom_list.xml

On src/package foldeR:
custom_list_view

```
public CustomViewAdapter(Context context, String text1, String text2) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_list, this, true);
    tvText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tvText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tvText1.setText(text1);
    tvText2.setText(text2);}
```

And then on the main activity, you must have a layout and run this code:

```
layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutToAddList);
CustomViewAdapter newView = new CustomViewAdapter(this, "text1", "text2");
layout.addView(newView);
```

and that's it!